# Merge spheres smoothly

Tags: modifiers

I have a reference image included below, I am trying to replicate the sphere effect where it not only deforms with the cube but also has a smooth and consistent blend between each sphere, including the deformation around the cube. I suppose if I could just get the spheres to combine as a single mesh I could bool out the cube and bevel the subsequent edge. Is there a way to union two objects but control the "smoothness" of the intersection?

I have tried metaballs, and also running a physics simulation with soft bodies but it isn't the same. I'm sure this is quite simple, but I can't find how to do it anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I would also try with metaballs then cut the mesh with a boolean?

Comment: @moonboots Metaballs just don't seem to be able to get the consistent gap between them. I did manage to get something looks okay with the metaballs, but I had the problem that the edge created on the metaball mesh by the boolean operation can't be bevelled without the faces going crazy - I tried merging the edge vertices by distance to clean up and it didn't work. Any tips?

Comment: instead of boolean you can cut in Sculpt mode but yes there's still the bevel to fix... Maybe do it with half sphere that you agglomerate, then remesh and sculpt to smooth the joints?

Comment: here is what it gives: https://zupimages.net/up/22/28/002q.jpg